# Abstraction of external service / API request and response

Tags: php, oop, single-responsibility-principle

> **TLDR:** Writing a service (in the model layer). It talks to ffmpeg. Where should *validation* go? Should I create a *service response object* so it is testable? How should it be structured?
>
> **Background:** I'm designing some classes to retrieve data from an external service. It could be an API, but in fact it's calls to **ffmpeg cli**, which in effect is an API to the conversion tools themselves.

When talking to an external service, where the data retrieved may not always be the same, how is it best to go about maintaining at least a consistent application state on your end so your application doesn't depend on the external service to work?

I have already separated out the classes thus far, trying to maintain [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) within them:

```
class CommandDispatcher { }
```

*The Command Dispatcher's sole job is to make a request for data (to ffmpeg) and retrieve the response for that data back*.

```
class Converter { }
```

*The converter's sole responsibility is to take user requests (like convert 1 to 2), and send the basics to the command dispatcher which handles the `exec()` calls.*

Here are my questions:

- When talking to an external API / service, should I be creating an `APIRequest` and an `APIResponse` object (in this case an `FFmpegResponse` object)?

I have seen examples of this for OAuth, where there is an OAuth response object. However, that's simple enough because calls to this are done over the HTTP protocol which tends to give back at minimum an error code and a message. Calls to something like ffmpeg don't guarantee a similar response (*ffmpeg may not be installed, for example*). Is this object merely a domain object (i.e. an entity: some class members and setters and getters)?

- Validation. If I am creating an `FFmpegResponse` object, whose job is it to put the data into the right members of the Response object?

Imagine ffmpeg isn't installed and the `CommandDispatcher` gets the response back empty. Is it up to the `CommandDispatcher` to then populate the `FFmpegResponse` object with an "ffmpeg not installed" error? Should I have a validation object do this?

Remember, I'm trying to stick to the Single Responsibility Principle here, so I'm thinking that the `CommandDispatcher` shouldn't care about whether the data is valid or not - it should merely ask for data and retrieve it. Where does my validation fit within the model layer for this service?

This isn't only for FFmpeg but will help for future external service calls. What is the best [practice] way to structure your code and classes to maintain SRP yet also a consistent application state regardless of whether or not the external service responds in an expected way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current structure, `CommandDispatcher` should be either an interface or an abstract class (depending on the necessity of abstract code). You would then create a concrete implementation: `FFMpegCommandDispatcher` which would encapsulate the understanding of ffmpeg specific responses.

Response objects will then take on a similar structure: `CommandResponse` would be an abstraction with the concrete implementation `FFMpegCommandResponse`.

It would be best to create a set of common error conditions (serviceNotAvailable, serviceNotInstalled, serviceDiedAHorribleAndBloodyDeath, etc). Your dispatcher implementation can then set a common error code on the response object and provider implementation specific details. ('Error 1984: FFMpeg is watching you')

If you're concerned (and I would be) about validating input as well. You could create a CommandRequest abstraction, and FFMpegRequest implementation, that will take user input and make sure that it's okay to be sent to the command line.

Comment: If the dispatcher sets the error code, this means it has to interpret the response from the cli call. Doesn't this violate SRP as it's also validating? The alternative is to pass whatever response is returned to the validation service, which in turn decides what is valid or not. Is this one better?

Comment: IMHO, a concrete implementation of a dispatcher can grok implementation responses and construct generic response objects without breaking SRP. I don't see that as 'validation' in the sense that I am imagining. 

Take a look at the RequestMediator in Guzzle: (http://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Guzzle/Http/Curl/RequestMediator.php). It receives a request, executes, parses the headers and body and returns a response.

In your model, the `CommandDispatcher` takes that responsibility. And, you can implement a request object that will contain input validation logic.

Comment: Ah okay, but doing it this way, I would have to duplicate the validation code if, say, the `CommandDispatcher` instead was talking to a database instead of the CLI, where as a custom validator means that it can validate whatever you throw at it, from cli, a db or another service, and it'll let you know if it's right or not (means less work for future implementors of `CommandDispatcher`). Any opinions on that? Maybe I'm abstracting out too much...

Comment: I think we're very close to the same idea. I guess that I'm seeing this as a lot of abstract code in CommandDispatcher and just the validation logic in FFMpegCommandDispatcher .. or PDOCommandDispatcher .. TwitterCommandDispatcher. And you're seeing it as a validator object that you pass into a more generalize dispatcher. Take a look at this for a basic structure of what I'm thinking, I speak better in code than in words (http://pastebin.com/nt5JncA2). ( If things look strange, I'm living in .NET land right now so I may have messed up syntax :/ )

Comment: Ah I see, I like it. It didn't seem like anyone wanted to answer this, so thanks very much for your answer and effort! :-)